# Codeigniter 3 Organize/get data by months of a table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table name 'competitions'

Structure of column is like this

```
id|gameTitle|username|username_p1|is_random|status|entry_fee|prize_money|created_at|updated_at
```

What I want is to get data of past 6 months. Where a user have played some number of random games in a month.

```
where is_random = 1
and username= 'anyUsername' or username_p1 = 'anyUsername'
```

From below query I get result of only one month.

```
SELECT gameTitle, id, COUNT(created_at)
FROM  `competitions_1_1` 
WHERE is_random =1
AND username =  'guppuboss'
OR username_p1 =  'guppuboss'
AND created_at
BETWEEN  '2016-08-25 18:02:51'
AND  '2016-09-26 17:09:57'
GROUP BY created_at
```

What I want to achive is some thing like this:

```
2016-09-26  | 20
2016-08-26  | 9
2016-07-26  | 33
```

Comment: Just to clearify, you want your result ro be the date and then the count right? If so, just alter your select statement to only select those too. No need to select anything else if you don't want them in your result, it will also make it easier when reading your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT gameTitle, id, month(created_at) as month, year(created_at) as year, COUNT(*) as count
FROM  `competitions_1_1` 
WHERE is_random =1
AND ( username =  'guppuboss'
OR username_p1 =  'guppuboss' )
AND created_at > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)   GROUP BY MONTH(created_at)
```

Comment: This query is perfect. It just solved my problem. and got me desired result. Thanks for your help...!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add grouping using round brackets....

```
SELECT gameTitle, COUNT(id) as total
FROM  `competitions_1_1` 
WHERE (is_random = 1
AND username =  'any_name')
OR (is_random = 1 AND username_p1 =  'any_name')
AND created_at >= now()-interval 6 month
```

I hope you will find your solution..let me know still having any issue